# Python + CSV files: How do I automatically create unique names for objects, and pull data from specific cells

Tags: python, csv

I have been taking an introduction to data science for archaeology course, and am currently struggling with the first (non-marked) piece of work. While I understand the overall logic of the code I’m meant to be writing and don't have problems writing it out in psudocode, I’m struggling a lot with syntax. I’ve asked my lecturer for help/advice, but my lecturer is not very good at explaining syntax. Sorry if this is super basic- I’m very new to programming.

What do I want to do is open each CSV file in a directory, creating a uniquely named object for it, storing data from particular cells within the CSV file in the object.

I have already defined the class for the objects (`Table`) in another module, and imported it. I’ve also defined the directory path. I cannot use pandas for this piece of work.

The only really relevant actual code I’ve written so far is:

```py
import os
import csv
from table import Table
from analysis import Analysis 

src_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
data_folder = os.path.join(src_folder,test_data")
os.chdir(data_folder)

for infile in os.listdir(data_folder):
    if infile.endswith('.csv'):
        # to check if working, delete from final
        print "Current File Being Processed is:  " + infile 
        # define object as instance of Table()
        with open(infile) as csvfile: 
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            # skips the header row
            next(reader, None)
            for row in reader:
               # prints fourth column to make sure its actually reading data
               print(row[3])
```

What I want to do here is automatically create a `Table()` object for each file that has a unique name. I also want to be able to define two values (`self.beta` and `self.alpha`) from specific cells within the CSV file, not from whole rows. Is there a way to do either of these?

Comment: You might want to add what you are going to do with the data after saving it in a data structure. There might be a better way to manage your datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing each `Table()` object in varaibles, i would create a dictionary with the filename of each csv file as the key.

So before the `for` loop declare an empty dictionary `csvs = {}`

Then for each csv file, I would save the table object as a value with the filename as the key.

Within the for loop (i.e. for each file)

```
csvs[infile] = Table(alpha=x, beta=y)
```

You will have to make sure that both alpha and beta can be set on initialisation of the object.

You could probabaly do this in a single line of code, look into dictionary comprehension.

You may want to save this python object, so you don't have to generate it each time. You could do this by using `pickle`.